# How to update without "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

There's a table with grouped rows that share a value in one column, but they very rarely differ in another column.

I need to be able to update the `portfolio_id` below when they don't differ, or optimally, at least don't differ in 90% of the cases (I realize this might be tricky though).

**Table Structure**

`mytable1`

```
table1id | parentgroup | portfolio_id
1        | 100         | 3
2        | 100         | 3
3        | 100         | 3
4        | 203         | 4
5        | 203         | 5
6        | 500         | 7
```

`mytable2` along with intended result

```
count | parentgroup | portfolio_id
    3 |         100 | (trying to fill with a 3)
    2 |         203 | (shouldn't fill since half the dots are split within 2 portfolios)
    1 |         500 | (trying to fill with a 7)
```

My query looks like

```
update mytable2 a
set portfolio_id = (select portfolio_id from mytable1 b
    where a.parentgroup = b.parentgroup)
where parentgroup is not null
```

But obviously I get the error

> SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option which uses a CTE with an update join:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT parentgroup, MAX(portfolio_id) AS portfolio_id
    FROM mytable1
    GROUP BY parentgroup
    HAVING MIN(portfolio_id) = MAX(portfolio_id)
)

UPDATE mytable2 a
SET portfolio_id = b.portfolio_id
FROM cte AS b
WHERE a.parentgroup = b.parentgroup;
```

The idea here is that the CTE finds, for each `parentgroup` in the first table, the singular value of `portfolio_id`, if a singular value exists.  Then, we update the second table by only targeting `parentgroup` groups which match to anything in the CTE.

Comment: SQL master. So quick that i have to wait to award you the tick. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that updates `mytable2` only if at least 90% of all `portfolio_id`s per `parentgroup` are identical:

```
WITH grps_to_upd AS (
   SELECT parentgroup,
          portfolio_id
   FROM (SELECT parentgroup,
                portfolio_id,
                my_ct,
                sum(my_ct) OVER (PARTITION BY parentgroup) AS grp_ct
         FROM (SELECT parentgroup,
                      portfolio_id,
                      count(*) AS my_ct
               FROM mytable1
               GROUP BY parentgroup, portfolio_id
              ) AS grp1
        ) AS grp2
   WHERE my_ct::double precision / grp_ct::double precision >= 0.9
)
UPDATE mytable2
SET portfolio_id = grps_to_upd.portfolio_id
FROM grps_to_upd
WHERE mytable2.parentgroup = grps_to_upd.parentgroup;
```

Comment: that is a sick sub query on sub query on the with. Wish I could also give you a tick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

portfolio_id, not an array field so that you have to ensure SELECT projection should return once at a time.

```
UPDATE mytable2 A
       SET portfolio_id = (SELECT portfolio_id FROM mytable1 B
                           WHERE A.parentgroup = B.parentgroup LIMIT 1)
       WHERE parentgroup IS NOT null
```

Comment: this will give me just a random portfolio_id that belongs to the group, bad solution